# Is it possible to clean up an audio recording of a lecture using some type of AI system?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, algorithm-request, audio-processing, signal-processing

Is it possible to clean up an audio recording of a lecture from a smartphone (i.e. remove the background noise) using some type of AI system?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible. Usually, the noise reduction is done using regular signal processing methods, such as spectral subtraction due to demand for low latency. But, of course, modern methods of deep learning are applicable to this problem. For example, the variational autoencoder is the first that comes to my mind, you can check this  [project](https://github.com/ghunkins/Voice-Denoising-AN). Another example you can look at is this [project](https://github.com/drethage/speech-denoising-wavenet), which is based on WaveNet.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll check those out .Think it's what I'm looking for, yeah. 
I don't really need realtime processing. I just have a bunch of audio files from lecture recordings that I'd like to "extract the speaker's voice" from as much as possible. So hopefully I can do that with this.
I'll mark your answer as the best answer when I've tried it out

Comment: Hello @igrinis thank you very much for your answer. It would be great if you can make a short video or a list of operations needed to use it. I'm not familiar with github project.